# How to access specific buttons on a collection view tin 4 buttons and 1 image view

Tags: collectionview

I am currently populating a collection view with images but at the same time have some button option.

How can I know which button I press if let's say it populated about 4 of those cells?
How do I make a code to handle that event?

Answer (score 0):

Add actions to each button in your collectionView cell. Or add one action to all of them and set tag for each button. Then in action method

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
//btn.superview will be your button parent view (cell for example)
```

Comment: yes I already added action to each button. But since the cell will get populated, so those actions will refer to the other cells as well. How do I determine which cell's button was pushed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer nerowolfe. I solved it by putting tag in the imgview during population of the cells..  then access it thru each button action event..

Comment: Great. Tag the answer as answered please